# problems to write big String to a file

Tags: java, string, file, base64

I am trying to write a String in Base64, this String represents a PDF file,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        cedula++;
        escribirArchivo.escribirInfoEnElArchivo(data1.append(pdf).append(",").append(cedula).toString());
        escribirArchivo.escribirInfoEnElArchivo(data2.append(pdf2).append(",").append(cedula).toString());
        escribirArchivo.escribirInfoEnElArchivo(data3.append(pdf3).append(",").append(cedula).toString());
    }
```

and this is my method to write a file

```
  public void escribirInfoEnElArchivo( String infoToWrite) {
    try {
        fileWriter.write(infoToWrite + "\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this consume around 2-3GB of ram in some point I ran out of memory and throws and error with Heap memory, how can I perform this in a better way?

Comment: Don't try to build the entire string in memory first.  Just write it to the file in pieces.

Comment: a [mcve] is needed here...what is `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `pdf`, `pdf2`, `pdf3`? are these really needed in memory? as posted they are being increased each 500 times

Comment: data 1, data 2, data3 are StringBuilder and pdf, pdf, pdf3 are Base64 String that represents three pdf's with different size

Comment: Are you deliberately not clearing your StringBuilders?  I imagine after appending `pdf + "," + cedula` 500 times, `data1` will be quite long and will use a lot of memory.

Comment: how can i clear it ?

Comment: i tried with setlength(0) and it works

Answer (score 1):

As azurefrog said in his comment, creating the entire string first before writing it is massively expensive for memory.  Instead of building the string and passing that to `escribirInfoEnElArchivo()`, just pass the pdf and use the file writer to write it from there.  If you need to append additional information, you can do that in `escribirInfoEnElArchivo()` after you write the pdf.